# Downloaded JDK 7, but not JRE 7?

Tags: java

So I've downloaded jdk7 pretty much since the first day I started using Ubuntu 12.04 so that I could start using Eclipse under the most up-to-date version of java. I built and completed a project with the Java 7 library, but when I tried to run its jar via the terminal, it said Java 7 was not compatible. In the terminal, I ran

```
java -version
```

and it said I had JRE6. But how is that possible if I installed jdk7? Should I install it separately?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you likely have to install it separately. If you install openjdk-7 from a 3rd-party PPA, they likely would've added the dependency on jre-7 into it. If you downloaded Oracle JDK 7, then you need Oracle JRE 7 (located [here](http://java.com/en/download/linux_manual.jsp?locale=en)).

Comment: But the oracle website says that jre is included when you download jdk

Comment: using the command `whereis java`, see if there are any executables in the Java 7 directory.